# Add azure ad group to tabular model in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, bism

I try to add a azure ad group to a Role to a tabular model in Visual Studio. I have  tried both to add the group through the visual studio (find user in the role editor) and change the code itself. But I get the same error when I try to open the solution:

*An error occurred while opening the model on the workspace database. Reason: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'ID cannot be specified for Azure Analysis Services role member: 'obj:xxxxxxx@yyyyyyyy'.*

Does anyone have any idea if it is possible to a add an ad group to the bism model in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Visual Studio specifics, but in [TMSL format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/roles-object-tmsl?view=asallproducts-allversions) you can use the following example to add a group as role member. Basically, just input `obj:object-id@tenant-id` as group name.

You need two things:

- **Object id** (group id) can be found for example in the Azure Portal, just search for the group
- **Tenant id** (directory id) can be found in the Azure Portal, go to Azure Active Directory and open the Properties tab.

```json
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "name": "Internet Sales Global",
      "description": "All users can query model data",
      "modelPermission": "read",
      "members": [
        {
          "memberName": "priya@adventureworks.com",
          "identityProvider": "AzureAD"
        },
        {
          "memberName": "obj:my-object-id@my-tenant-id",
          "identityProvider": "AzureAD"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

See also the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46228660/4126843).